# Object Fallback Optimization

Tags: html, optimization, object, pageload, fallback

I have an object loading a flash animation with an image as a fallback.

When I look at the resources being loaded on page load, the fallback image appears to be downloaded regardless of whether or not flash is detected, which seems to be wasteful and inefficient (especially if the fallback image is large).

What's a clean way to ensure the fallback image isn't loaded if the object tag detects flash?

I've already looked at the get_browser() PHP function and it doesn't appear to be a viable option.

Here's a code outline:

```
<object>
  <param name="movie" value="..." />
  <param name="play" value="true" />
    <div id="frontpagefallback">    
      <img src="..." width="..." alt="..." usemap="#homeMap" />
    </div>
</object>
```

Comment: Could you show some code demonstrating how you implemented this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have this image in place in the `div` or whatever, and that you repopulate this `div` with the Flash content, if Flash is available.  If so, yes, the behavior you are seeing is normal.

What you need to do is determine in Javascript if Flash is installed, and then decide whether to populate that `div` with the image content, or the Flash content.  How you do this depends on how you are loading the flash.  I believe SWFObject can do this for you.

Generally though, it is fine to put that image there by default.  What if someone loads your page that isn't capable of running your Javascript to detect flash?  What about non-browsers on your page, such as search engines?

Comment: That's why I was hoping there was a server side solution to put in the detection logic.

Comment: @Eric, there isn't.  This is a client-side issue.  Flash is not exposed in the User-Agent or anything.